# How to auto increment in vb form

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I am using vb.net and SQL Server as backend; I want to auto generate `id` which is created as primary key and is there any way to auto generate id with alphanumeric ex:- cx10001,cx1002

Comment: You could add an extra column to the table and use the formula option in the column properties to join your text field with an ID

Comment: Let your database generate your primary key for you.  Since you are using sql server, you can add a computed field to your table for your alphanumeric stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution is to use

- an `ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)` column to get SQL Server to handle the automatic increment of your numeric value
- a **computed, persisted** column to convert that numeric value to the value you need

So try this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable
(
     ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
     YourOtherId AS 'cx' + RIGHT('00000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(5)), 5) PERSISTED,
     .... your other columns here....
)
```

Now, every time you insert a row into `YourTable` without specifying values for `ID` or `YourOtherID`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(Col1, Col2, ..., ColN)
VALUES (Val1, Val2, ....., ValN)
```

then SQL Server will **automatically and safely** increase your `ID` value, and `YourOtherID` will contain values like `cx00001`, `cx00002`,...... and so on - automatically, safely, reliably, no duplicates.